# Leaving France after losing visa and entering on a new passport

Tags: visas

I'm a US exchange student for the year in France, and my time here is about to end. I went home for Christmas and (stupidly) lost my passport, which contained my student visa and OFII stamp. I was able to get a new passport overnight and return to France, and I suppose I re-entered on a Schengen visa waiver. I was told that I need to apply for a biometric residency permit (carte de séjour), which is what I've been trying to do.

I had to get multiple documents sent from the States, get them translated, wait on the administration, send in more documents... in short it's been a mess. I've also dragged my feet on this a bit, which is my fault, but I underestimated the sluggishness of the French administration. I started this process two months ago, and today I was told that if my documents are in order it'll take three to four weeks for a residency card to be issued. The issue is that my lease will be running up here in two and I really just want to go home. I can't afford multiple weeks in a hotel or Airbnb (not to mention meals).

What's the worst thing that can happen to me if I just leave with my existing paperwork? I have...

- a photocopy of my old visa and the OFII stamp
- a photocopy of my old passport
- a European health insurance card
- stamped proof of enrolment in university
- stamped statement of enrolment in their national healthcare system (predating my current entry stamps)
- proof of a bank account here
- proof of address (pre-dating my current entry stamps)
- a government document issued for obtaining my visa, verifying the location of my course, the institution, and the dates of my studies with my name and DOB

On top of all of that I have a US driver's license. The administration currently has my birth certificate and a French translation, but I should be able to get that back. If I go through passport control with this, how much trouble will I have? I'm expecting to be pulled aside and questioned, but surely with that much documentation I wouldn't be fined or banned from re-entry, right?

Thank you so much for any advice. My university has been no help and I'm struggling to figure out what to do.

Comment: When did you submit the application for the *carte de séjour*, and do you have proof of submitting it? It may be important to show that you applied within 90 days of entering.

Comment: The application was submitted in early April, I'd have to look for the exact date. I was about two weeks inside of the 90 days when I applied. The letter they gave me requesting additional documents is misdated to early March, although that doesn't necessarily hurt me. I will certainly have that letter with me.

I've been trying to decide if it'd be better to go by rail or air to London, where I'll be flying out of (starting studies there in the fall and have a round-trip). The chunnel passport control is on the British side, and would also be after I travel so it might be better for me.

Comment: VTC: it's difficult to tease out the question, which might be overstay ... or not. OP has not returned since asking the question.